# Performance: large table mousehover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr data-parent="0" data-id="1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="1" data-id="2">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="1" data-id="3">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-parent="3" data-id="4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where `data-parent` points to the `data-id` of another row.

**JQUERY/JS**

```
$("tr[data-parent='" + id + "']").css("background-color", "#1ba1e2").each(function () {
    $("tr[data-parent='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").css("background-color", "#75F7FF").each(function () {
        $("tr[data-parent='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").css("background-color", "#98E8E3").each(function () {
            $("tr[data-parent='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").css("background-color", "#B6DCE8")
    });});});
```

(I know that I could have written a recursive function as well, that's not the point right now)

When someone mouse-overs a TR, I want that row to be one color, all the rows that has the hovered row as parent, another color, the grandchildren another color etc (for several levels deep).

Now, for 100 rows, this isn't a problem, but my data contains around 30 000 rows, and that's where it starts to go wrong, several-seconds-of-freezing-wrong.

How can I optimise this code?

For your and my convenience: a jsFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/dawdg4sj/

Comment: I would suggest that if you have 30,000 rows you should look in to having it as a searchable/pagable list. Having that much data presented to a user is counter-productive.

Comment: Can you preprocess the data such that each row has attributes `data-ancestor-<n>`, where `n` marks the number of generations relative to  the current node? Thus you could avoid explicit iterations ( e.g. using `$("tr[data-ancestor-2='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").css("background-color", "#98E8E3");` to color grand-children of `this`).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am aware of the too-much-data issue, and we're actively looking for better ways to make the data pool smaller, but for now, we have to work with what is given, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, 30'000 rows in a single table is a usability issue; some browser won't even be able to handle such a monster well. Try to find a way to cut the size down.

Now some solutions.

You can use `id` instead of `data-id`. The browser keeps an efficient lookup table for elements with IDs. In jQuery, you can then use `$('#'+id)` to look up the DOM nodes which is very fast (no scanning of the whole tree which is going to be huge if you have 30K rows).

If you can't do this, then keep the references in a JavaScript object where you can get the parents/children with simple key lookups, i.e. `lookup[parentId]` should return the TR node with this `parentId`. That means parsing the table once or not using `data` attributes at all.

An alternative to this is to use jQuery's `data()` function which allows you to attach arbitrary values to a DOM node. That way, you can look up the DOM nodes for the related nodes and keep the references instead of searching the whole document each time.

Lastly, the number of levels and the number of nodes per level has a huge influence on performance. Your algorithm is O(N1*N2*N3*N4*...*NM) (where M is the number of levels). So if you have N2=5, N2=3, N3=4, then you already have to process 5*3*4*... nodes. No matter how you do the lookup, changing 1000 nodes in a huge document is expensive.

Comment: Thank you, this, combined with what the people at codereview told me, should give me enough of an improvement to solve the issues. We're looking for ways to decrease the row-count as well.